# Display a matching line and the closest preceding line matching another pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have this requirement where `show mac address table` of a switch will list 1000 entries .

```
file1:

switch_1#show mac address table
AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA port 47
BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB port 48
.
.
.
DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD port 50
```

```
file2:

switch_2#show mac address table
AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA port 47
BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB port 48
.
.
.
DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD port 45
```

I need to find a way to display the line containing `DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD` and once this occurs, it should search few lines above and print the hostname containing line as well

So the output should look like:

```
switch_1#show mac address table
DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD port 50
switch_2#show mac address table
DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD port 45
```

`file1`, `file2`are stored in the same directory
(these are just examples, there is like 100+ files/switches and MAC needs to be filtered along with the switch names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**awk solution**

If we get a line with a hash, store it in variable a.

If we get a line with a matching MAC address, print variable a, along with the current line.

```
$ awk '/#/{a=$0}/^DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD/{print a"\n"$0}' file1 file2
switch_1#show mac address table
DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD port 50
switch_2#show mac address table
DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD port 45
$
```

**sed solution**

If we get a line with a hash, place it in the hold space (`h`).

If we get a line with a matching MAC address, append to the pattern space (`H`), copy hold space to pattern space (`g`), print pattern space (`p`)

```
$ sed -n '/#/h;/^DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD/{H;g;p}' file1 file2
switch_1#show mac address table
DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD port 50
switch_2#show mac address table
DD:DD:DD:DD:DD:DD port 45
$
```

Comment: or `sed '//h;//!d;H;x` if you're a golfer...

Comment: is it possible to print one line next to the matching regexp in the awk solution? meaning, If we get a line with a hash, store it in variable a, If we get a line with a matching MAC address, print variable a, along with the current line and the immediate next line.

Comment: Maran - that probably warrants an entirely new question, with new examples of input/output.